# Finding a string using Regular Expression in visual studio 2017

Tags: regex, text, expression

Hello can anyone help me create a reg expression that would find this in my project?

@Html.Raw(customItem.Fields["Body"].ToString())

I need to change out the "customItem" and "Body" text with a wild card.

Comment: What do you mean by `wild card`?  What are the replacements?

Comment: Something like this @Html.Raw(.*?.Fields[".*?"].ToString())

Comment: Wait...is what you wrote about the actual _replacement_, or is that your suggestion of a pattern to use to find the text to be replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\@Html\.Raw\((.+?)\.Fields\["(.+?)"\]\.ToString\(\)\)
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/lyfLlp/1)